# How to open a local html file in a new tab from a modal dialog?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am building an R Shiny app and have an `actionButton` that when clicked opens up a set of instructions. These instructions are saved in an HTML file that is saved in my /Data folder. Since the `modalDialog` that opens up is a bit long, I want to offer the user an option to click a link in the dialog that will open up the same HTML file in a new tab.

I have tried adding an `href` within my HTML file but that doesn't seem to work (and is possibly recursive?).

The minimum code required to recreate this is here:

```
hsHTML <- htmlTemplate("Health stats user guide.html")

ui <- mainPanel( id = "mainpanel",
  actionButton("hsinstructions","User guide")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$hsinstructions, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = HTML("<font size='6'>User Guide</font>"),
      HTML(paste0(hsHTML)),
      easyClose = T,
      footer = modalButton("Dismiss")
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And an abbreviated version of the HTML that the "Health stats user guide.html" contains is the following:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <font size='5'><strong>Instructions</strong></font><br>
      <a href="Health stats user guide.html" target="_blank">Open in new tab</a><br>
   </body>
</html>
```

What I want is the "Open in new tab" link to open the same HTML file but in a new tab. Currently, it just returns a new tab that says "Not Found".

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space you have included in the html path

do : heatlth-stats-user-guide.html

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as it still says "Not found".